# How to create JSON file from java without duplicating element?

Tags: java, json, duplicates

I'm trying to make a simple dictionary program based on server-client socket communication. I'm trying to save user word and meaning input as a JSON file (which is dictionary data to search later on) but when I do add query it ends up with having duplicated JSON objects

for example, if I add happy and then weather and hello, the result written in JSON file is 
like below

```
{"hello":"greeting"}{"happy":"joy","hello":"greeting"} 
{"happy":"joy","weather":"cold","hello":"greeting"}`
```

instead of getting
`{"hello":"greeting"}{"happy":"joy"}{"weather":"cold"}` like I wanted

how can I fix this problem?

my code for that function is

```
case "add":{
FileWriter dictionaryWriter = new FileWriter("dictionary.json",true);

//split command again into 2 part now using delimiter ","
String break2[] = msgBreak[1].split(",");
String word = break2[0];
String meaning = break2[1];

dictionary.put(word, meaning);
System.out.println("Writing... " + word+":"+meaning); 
dictionaryWriter.write(dictionary.toString());
//flush remain byte
dictionaryWriter.flush();
//close writer
dictionaryWriter.close();

break;}
```

this function is in while(true) loop with other dictionary functions

I tried to remove the appending file part, but when I remove the (,true) part the duplication error stopped but whenever I get a new connection, new dictionary file is created instead of having all data saved.

If anyone can help me solve this problem, I would appreciate it a lot!
Thanks you in advance.

Comment: use hashmap or arraymap .. it will replace your previous data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new dictionary every time instead of using the existing one

```
Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
dictionary.put(word, meaning);
...
```